# Automatic LaTeX code formatting (similar to clang-format)

Tags: sourcecode, tools, ide

There are tools such as [clang-format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) that take e.g. an "ugly" (unformatted) C++ source code file and apply specific indentation and other rules to make the code more readable.

Is there such a tool that can automatically format LaTeX source code? I want to somehow keep my LaTeX files clean and consistent among contributors.

Comment: There is a [`latexindent`](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexindent?lang=en) package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tool [latexindent](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexindent) that was suggested by @muzimuzhi-Z in a comment worked for me. This Perl script seems to be very powerful, but starting is easy:

### Installation

I already had an older version (probably through `texlive-full`), but since this project is quite actively developed, I decided to get the latest version:

1. I got the source from [its official repository GitHub](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl)
2. I installed any missing dependencies with `sudo ./helper-scripts/latexindent-module-installer.pl`
3. I added it to my path in my `~/.bashrc`: `export PATH="/path/to/latexindent.pl:$PATH"`

### Usage

Default options, overwriting the file (`-w`), without writing a copy to the terminal (`-s`):

```
latexindent.pl -w -s myfile.tex
```

This will keep a backup of the original file `.bak0` (or `.bak1` etc). If you have this in a repository, you may want to add `*.bak?` in your `.gitignore`.

You can also specify your own formatting style in a `yml` file, like this: `latexindent.pl -l mysettings.yml myfile.tex`.

Comment: Glad you got it to work :) happy indentation!

Answer (score 0):

emacs (surpise!) comes with LaTeX support out-of-the-box, much, *much* fancier support gives AUC-TeX (and RefTeX for cross-references and citing bibliographies). All standard packages, check the package index.

In any case, I format my LaTeX source files to contain a phrase each line, end with punctuation, ... That way (suggested a *long* while back when writing troff (!) for my thesis, using vi...) changes often mean delete/insert or move a line/lines around, checking for boo-boos like "an thesis" or "a elephant" or "the the case" can be done with line-oriented tools (fix even automated with a simple regex replace). Today I stash it in git, the format has the added benefit that adding/deleting e.g. a word doesn't reflow the paragraph, so version differences do highlight real changes.

Yes, reformatting that way is a chore that has to be done by hand... but it is needed once (and keep it up later).

Comment: Thanks! I was not looking for an editor-specific tool, but one may also be interested to the package [atom-beautify](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify) for Atom.